# HDMI EDID Emulator that supports ultrawides?

Tags: hdmi

I need either,

- An HDMI passthrough providing EDID emulation that supports ultrawide resolutions like 5120x1440.
- A programmable HDMI passthrough that provides EDID Emulator that I can set the EDID information it provides.

I'm thinking outside the box, and [because OSX requires root to override EDID and doesn't allow the users to enter custom mode lines or resolutions for HDMI outputs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/455445/76955), I have look for something external to a Macbook that can do this.